# Wso2 : Unable to change user-mgt.xml

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2, I was trying to refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username however once I change the file at specified location as per the documentation in <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml , after server restart it changes the file again with default settings.

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the version of IS that you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a WSO2 IS version 5.9.0 or later, it uses `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file as a central configuration file. That's what the XML changes get rest when the server restarts.
For more info: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/references/new-configuration-model/

Refer to the documentation relevant to the product version.

5.11.0 - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/#using-email-address-as-the-username

5.10.0 - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.10.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/#using-email-address-as-the-username

5.9.0 - https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/using-email-address-as-the-username/#using-email-address-as-the-username

Comment: Thanks I am using 5.11.0 and now via console UI I am able to add new user as email id, however via SCIM unable to add new user,I see log trace [2021-05-18 20:12:34,967] []  exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet .. any suggustions ?

Comment: I will create seperate ticket for the same, the raised issue is resolved. I will further investigate more on the subsequent issues . Thanks

Comment: It was build issue and now both the flow is working so I can confirm we can close the issue. Thanks for the support.